# Execution Reverted due to UniswapV2-Pair creation in constructor

Tags: solidity, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, sepolia, uniswapv2

I am new to Blockchain development, so bear with me.

I successfully deployed my first contract, but if I try to add a Uniswap V2 Pair creation inside the constructor, I always get the error "Execution reverted" on the blockchain.

I am using Sepolia Testnet and environment setup is hardhat with VS Code.

Here is my code:

```js
contract Test is ERC20{
    IUniswapV2Pair public immutable uniswapV2Pair;
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable uniswapV2Router;
    constructor() ERC20('TES','Test'){
        _mint(msg.sender, 2000000 * 10**18);
        uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);
        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Pair(
            IUniswapV2Factory(uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), uniswapV2Router.WETH())
        );

    }
}
```

Here is the tx / contract:
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x576Ffe611264F9E884702c98a0978Ed3c3D4DC34

What is wrong? My wallet has approx 1 Sepolia-ETH which I think should be sufficient to deploy this?

Comment: I think I have to use a different uniswap address for uniswap v2 on sepolia , i read that on reddit: 0xC532a74256D3Db42D0Bf7a0400fEFDbad7694008 
is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **UniswapV2Router02** address you're using is not available for the Sepolia testnet. Instead, the corresponding address for the Sepolia testnet is
[0xC532a74256D3Db42D0Bf7a0400fEFDbad7694008](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xC532a74256D3Db42D0Bf7a0400fEFDbad7694008).

```js
uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0xC532a74256D3Db42D0Bf7a0400fEFDbad7694008);
```

Using this address should ensure that your deployment works correctly.